# Замена определенного символа

Tags: javascript

Пользователь прописывает букву "а", а получает "А". При этом это должно работать только на этот символ. Как подобное возможно реализовать?

Comment: 1) `if (char == 'a') char = 'A';` 2) `str = str.replace(/a/g,'A')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function replace(str,charOld, charNew){
   return str.replace(new RegExp(charOld, 'g'), charNew);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inp").on("input", function(){
     $("#res").text(replace($(this).val(),"a","*"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp">
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш код может в текстовом поле динамически изменять букву? (При наборе текста пользователем?)

Comment: @theworstprogrammer дополнил немного, посмотрите (заменяется англ. буква "a" на "*") при вводе в поле

Answer (score 0):

```
txt="пример текста";
txt=txt.replace("а","А");
```